# Show that if $T$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical then $T$ has a non-atomic model of size $\aleph_1$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Exactly as the title stated:

Show that if $T$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical then $T$ has a non-atomic model of size $\aleph_1$

Would like some pointers on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the language is countable. Then any non $\aleph_0$-categorical theory has a countable model $M$ that is not prime, hence not atomic. Let $a\in M$ realize a non isolated type (over $\varnothing$). Than every elementary extension of $M$ containing $a$ also realizes the same type.

I do not the answer for uncountable languages.

Comment: Your answer basically works for languages of size $\aleph_1$ as well. All you need to have a non-atomic model of any size $\geq|L|$ is to have a  non-isolated type in $S^n(\emptyset)$ for some $n$ (realize it and use Lowenheim-Skolem). But by compactness, if a Stone space is infinite, it must contain some non-isolated type. Hence if there is no non-atomic model of size $\aleph_1$, then $S^n(\emptyset)$ is finite for all $n$, which implies $\aleph_0$-categoricity no matter how many symbols are in the language.

Comment: Of course, if the language has size $>\aleph_1$, then there might not be any model of size $\aleph_1$ at all, so the statement is false.

Comment: @AlexKruckman How do you know that $S^n(\varnothing)$ is infinite? Ryll-Nardzewski theorem does not apply to uncountable languages. (There may be some trivial argument, which I do not see it right now.)

Comment: It seems to me that the implication "finite stone spaces $\rightarrow$ $\aleph_0$-categorical" doesn't require a countable language. Of course, if the stone spaces are all finite, then there are only finitely many formulas in $n$ variables up to equivalence, so the language is essentially countable anyway...

Comment: @PrimoPetri when you say "every elementary extension of $M$ containing a also realizes the same type", how do you know the elementary extension is of size $\aleph_1$?, or is that not what you meant to say?

Comment: @chibro2 By the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem.